# C++ use template in gettor function

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose there are two types of object A and B and two getter functions

```
objA* getA(int id) and objB* getB(int id)
```

Object A and B are mutually exclusive. i.e. if a object is A, then it is not B.
When to find a object using an ID, the code I use is below. So I am just wondering if the function can return non-NULL object pointer which may point to A or B using template. Or return null if the id is invalid.

```
void find(int id)
{
    objA* pa = getA(id);
    if (pa != NULL)
    {
      return;
    }

    objB* pb = getB(id);
    if (pb != NULL)
    {
      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) has what you need.  It's an abstraction for a single object that might be one of several types.  Your function signature then becomes:

```
boost::variant<A*, B*> find(int id);
```